# Finding out the drive letters previously used by my PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bios, drive-letter

My PC was disconnected from main power over night and it seems that the BIOS has lost information about the drives. It was unable to boot, so I had to enter the BIOS first and select the boot drive. It's able to boot again now.

However, Windows has assigned drive letters from scratch. Except for my boot drive (`C:`), all other drives are now named alphabetically (`D:`, `E:`, ...). This is probably due to the fact that their order in BIOS is also different now.

The new drive letters have major impact on installed programs, e.g. MS Office (which happened to be the first to complain).

Is there a way to find out which drive had which drive letter before all that reordering began?

I didn't take any notes about them and I personally didn't really care about the drive letters since I identify the drives by their label. I'll be able to find all my data, but I need to be able to run programs as well.

I know how to change drive letters, but I need to know what to change it to.

I have Windows 7 x64 SP1 and I've tried the following recommended questions

- [Motherboard replaced, drive letter screwed, not booting](https://superuser.com/questions/598690/motherboard-replaced-drive-letter-screwed-not-booting), which is the blue screen 7B, which I had before. I was able to fix this by adjusting the boot order in BIOS
- [Windows 7 - Drive letters spontaneously changed, can't boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1061085/windows-7-drive-letters-spontaneously-changed-cant-boot), is basically the problem I have, but the guy there knows the original drive letters which I don't
- [Hard drive letter incorrectly reassigned](https://superuser.com/questions/294334/hard-drive-letter-incorrectly-reassigned), which explains how to change a drive letter. I already know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Nirsoft LastActivityView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_activity_view.html) (a quite scary program BTW), I could figure out which files and folders I accessed recently. Since it lists them by date and time, it was possible to ignore things I did after the boot problem occured (i.e. today in my case). Sorting by full path was also helpful.

By searching the folders and files on the new drive letters, I was able to create a mapping for all five drive letters.

I then went into disk management and reassigned the drive letters.